# C++ Replace enum with instances of class. Avoid heap allocation

Tags: c++, design-patterns, enums

I want to replace this enum:
`enum{ eTagA, eTagB,...}`.

With instances of classes. This allows to append new tags, without modifying the enum.
I've got following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <list>

struct TagBase {
    bool operator== (const TagBase& other) const {
        return typeid(*this) == typeid(other);
    }

    bool operator!= (const TagBase& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
    
    virtual ~TagBase() = default;
};

bool operator== (const std::unique_ptr<TagBase>& lhs, const TagBase& base) {
    return base == *(lhs.get());
}

class Namespace {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void AddTag() {
        tags.push_back(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T()));
    }
    
    bool HasTag(const TagBase& tag) const {
        return std::find(std::begin(tags), std::end(tags), tag) != tags.end();
    }

private:
    // using of std::unique_ptr is the only way?
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<TagBase>> tags;
};

struct TagA: public TagBase {};
struct TagB: public TagBase {};
struct TagC: public TagBase {};

int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    Namespace nm;
    
    nm.AddTag<TagA>();
    nm.AddTag<TagB>();
    
    assert(nm.HasTag(TagA{}));
    assert(nm.HasTag(TagB{}));
    assert(nm.HasTag(TagC{}) == false);
}
```

It works, but I have some thoughts about:

1. Using **"typeid"** in this context is appropriate? Is this portable?
2. I can't use raw TagBase class in "std:list" because of slicing. Can I avoid to use "unique_ptr" because of heap allocation?
3. Maybe there is a better pattern to do this?

I also tried to do this with intense use of templates(std::is_same ... etc) but haven't got proper solution.

Comment: I'm sure that there's a "better pattern" for this, but to figure out what it is, it is necessary to know what is the real problem to which the shown code is believed to be the solution for. Perhaps if the actual problem gets described, a more appropriate C++ solution becomes obvious.

Comment: As I described, I've a class that manages different placements on the screen(paceholders). I want to allow to the users this this class to define new placements and append elements to them. Now I have big enum and every person who what to add new placement need to append this enum with a new value. Of course I can use string or number as unique id, but this looks isn't very good as for me.

Comment: "Define" arbitrary "new placements" automatically means dynamic allocation. This cannot be eliminated, by definition, so worrying about using `unique_ptr` is pointless. You're already using dynamic allocation by the virtue of using `std::list` or any other container. It's going to be much simpler to use a simple `std::unordered_map` where the key is the tag name. "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to clog up the drain" -- Scotty, Star Trek III.

Comment: Thanks for clarification to you and Scotty from Star Trek :) I tried to use raw TagBase as list member. But slicing had another opinion to this...

Comment: It looks like you're implementing a set. Why don't you instead just simply use [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)?

Comment: @ErdalKüçük using of std::set it was just for purpose of demo. I agree that it's not the best container to use here.

Comment: Yeah, but if you want an enumeration of classes (that is what i understand), a set is what you're looking for. Maybe i miss something here.

Comment: Sounds like you just want a `std::/*unordered_*/map<std::string, std::size_t>tags;`.  You can keep track of the last value you added to the map and just use the next value when adding a key.  Using `size_t` gives you a 64bit value space which should be more enumerators then you'll ever need.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük yep. But the problem not in the container. I want to have dynamically allocate new enum items. So the questions are - can I avoid dynamic allocation. Sam Varshavchik  gave answer for this. So the last one if I can use typeid for this, I can use something else :)

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike as I mentioned above, problem not in container. Problem is how to extend enum. And I don't like typeid itself.

Comment: Enums represent different values. Your tag type doesn't have any values. You are abusing the typeid the compiler generates as your values (with the problems you described). If don't want to limit yourself to the values of an enum (adding new values dynamically at runtime), you could easily use an `int` instead, or your own type containing an `int` as identifier. But you'd have to manage your values dynamically at runtime. For generating new, unused values, you'd need a (thread-safe) counter, or you could use UUIDs, or you could use an `std::set` to find out which values are already in use.

Comment: @DmytroBorysov I gave you an option on how to extend the enum.  wrap a `map` in a class and keep track of the last value you use when adding a new key to the map.  When you add another key give it the value of the last key used plus one, then update the value of the last key used.

Comment: @Jens sure I can use int or something else. But it's not friendly for users for this class and you can't avoid duplication. And with classes it looks better as for me:)

Comment: From your implementation, `std::unordered_set<std::type_info>` does the stuff. No need of inheritance...

Comment: @Jarod42 in case without inheritance what you will pass to nm.HasTag(TagB{}) method to check if namespace contains this tag?

Comment: Like [that Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6vT36dK4P).

Comment: @DmytroBorysov how about using variant+visit instead of dynamic dispatch? That way you'll have it all on the stack and with value semantics. On the other hand, you'll need to know all the types upfront.

Comment: Ah, now I understand! Thanks @Jarod42. I didn't get it from the first time you wrote. Thank you for your demo!

Comment: @alagner can you pls show small example of this ?

Comment: So you don't really want to generate new values dynamically at runtime, but instead want to define different values (known at compile time) across different modules of your application? Using simple (value type) constants doesn't avoid duplicates, whereas using a a polymorphic class can result in the slicing problem you described. Maybe a solution could be a "polymorphic value type". See https://www.foonathan.net/2020/01/type-erasure/

Comment: @DmytroBorysov more-less this way: https://godbolt.org/z/5z3e3e9EK

Comment: @Jens yes, all these values are knows at compilation time. Thanks for the link, I'm looking on it!

Comment: @alagner interesting. Thanks for the another way to do this! will also check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, `std::unordered_set<std::type_index>` seems to do the job:

```
class Namespace {
public:
    Namespace() = default;

    template<typename T>
    void AddTag() {
        tags.insert(typeid(T));
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool HasTag() const {
        return tags.find(typeid(T)) != tags.end();
    }

private:
    std::unordered_set<std::type_index> tags;
};

struct TagA{};
struct TagB {};
struct TagC {};

int main ()
{
    Namespace nm;
    
    nm.AddTag<TagA>();
    nm.AddTag<TagB>();
    
    assert(nm.HasTag<TagA>());
    assert(nm.HasTag<TagB>());
    assert(nm.HasTag<TagC>() == false);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KfG6PcdaW)

Comment: @DmytroBorysov In comments you wrote things like *"can use string or number as unique id, but this looks isn't very good as for me"*, *"the questions are - can I avoid dynamic allocation"*, *"all these values are knows at compilation time"*. And here you've got an answer that uses some unique ids from RTTI bloat along with dynamic allocations to produce results not usable at compilation time that does not look anything like an enum replacement.

Comment: @user7860670 The  motivation is the design(not performance, etc). Question about allocations is side-effect. We have many different ways to achieve same result as Jarod42 did.  I want to replace  the enum member with defining a new class. Yes, you're right, we moved defining an enum member to RTTI. It's not the same as enum, but it achieve same goal - to have enumeration of values known at compilation time. In case of enums - it's enum members in case of classes - it's different types(classes). You can match to class Name, not to Enum::Field. So it's matter of design :)

Comment: @user7860670 But I agree, it's not the most elegant way. But after c++ introduced "std::enable_if" it's the elegance became very abstract.